# How to get the latest date from start date based on process in Excel

Tags: excel

I’m trying get the latest date from my start date in excel based on the process. Each individual process terminate on a different day from start date. Some there days or some 7 days etc. how do I get the exact latest date in excel . Someone please help

If statement or formula in excel

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data and your expected output. What have you tried so far, where got you stuck? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Learn about how dates are represented in Excel: today (19-Aug-2023) is 45157 as far as Excel is concerned. Yesterday is 45156, tomorrow is 45158 (see a pattern here?). These integer values can be formatted to appear as dates (eg 19-Aug-2023 or 19/08/2023 or even 08/19/2023 or quite a few others). But they remain integers. Even when formatted they can be subtracted to find the difference in days between two dates. Similarly, days can be added to date to find a future date.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the dates are in a single column as you do not indicate any difficulty with them of a "physical" nature. So one need not worry about collecting them into a useful arrangement. Perhaps column B with the processes in column A.

As `DMM` points out, Excel stores dates as integer numbers beginning with 0 being 1900-01-00, or January 0, 1900. So 1 is 1900-01-01, and so on until the year 9999 is finished. It stores time as a decimal value, so a date AND time is actually something like "34576.2488". Sicne dates start at 0 and times at .0, there are never negatives and in fact, Excel will error on such a value presented to it as a date. (So if you ever need to use earlier dates, present them as simple numbers, not as dates, and do the work to interpret the result as a pre-1900 date yourself.)

This will matter at the end, as a consideration, though it will not affect the actual finding of the latest date in the set.

Excel has two functions that can find the maximum value in a set of value. `MAX` finds the single maximum value and returns that single value so not anything you and I would call an array. Use it in the middle of a longer formula and only the single value will carry through to the rest of the calculation. Something that is sometimes very obnoxious, and sometimes very desirable and useful. Very straightforward. Seven occurrences of the maximum value? It return it, as a single result, and that's that.

`LARGE` can do the same, but it can also return more than one result AND it can return the "however-eth many" at the high end. So if you want the top five finishers in some competition, specifying "5" will give you the fifth highest value and specifying {1,2,3,4,5} will give you the top five values. Note that while that last returns the five top competitors and is desirable, perhaps you want to know the top five score values, so if there were seven of the maximum scored, it would not work out as it would return the first five of those it ran across and give you five 7's. But you can still use it as you just use something like `UNIQUE` on the data set to get only one of any particular score. Then use `LARGE`. So... it has complexities.

Your situation seems simple, except for the one consideration I promised. So `MAX` is the function for you. You'd use it like so:  `MAX(B1:B100)`.

Now the consideration. So long as you have exactly dates only, so only integers in the set of dates (if you look at each cell in the column using the Formula Bar's view and all are integers, even though they of course look like dates viewed from the sheet itself), the above will do nicely. And in the exact problem presented, it still will even if the dates are really date and time, some not integers, rather values like 34659.9932. Notice that one can format such a value only to display the date and Excel is happy to do so which would hide the fact of time information existing.

In the presented problem, it would not matter, except for when you want the integer date and for that itself to be displayed, not something formatted as a date because you'd see the decimal value with the integer and be torqued a bit. You could then "integerize" it which can be done about six different ways.

In another use you might run into sometime it could be important. In that case, you wrap the range reference in the formula with a method for making the values integers only, and then apply `MAX` (or `LARGE`).

But if you wanted to find a maximum of a timespan, so say you had start dates and end dates for something, you could get a wrong result. Say an end of 1000.002 and a start of 990.992, and you'd get an integer timespan of 9 but would probably expect a result of 10. As a practical matter, it might not matter as either the 9 would be the real maximum, or a different pair might give a result of 10 and that's reported to you. But if you were looking, say, for any span 10 days or more, perhaps as input in a formula to a `FILTER` function, then the record would not appear in your results. So there's consideration of this possibility and whether it would affect your results.

And in your case here, computers usually are rather precise, so if the processes are computer processes, the log they come from might include the time in the "date" value and set the stage for this issue.

That pairs then with the length of my answer when a simple "Just use this" might have been desired... it is very much a matter of the devil is in the details and so the more you know about each element of the problem and its solution, the better you can decide how to solve the exact situation you have.